# How do I format data from an Inquirer output into markdown file

Tags: javascript, markdown, inquirerjs

I'm making a README generator for a school project, and my inquirer prompts are all functioning fine, but when I call the data from this prompt:

```js
{
  type: "checkbox",
  name: "languages",
  message: "What languages/technologies were used to create this project?",
  choices: ["HTML", "CSS", "JavaScript", "Node.JS"],
}
```

I am using template literal to incorporate. The corresponding markdown entry appears as such:

```
${data.languages}
## Technologies Used
HTML,CSS,JavaScript,Node.JS
```

with no spaces. My preference would be to have them appear as a list. How would I go about formatting this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code used to take the selections and incorporate them into the markdown

Comment: I have edited to add template literal.

Answer (score 1):

Inquirer's `checkbox` prompt resolves with an array.

To format that as Markdown, you would use something like

```js
inquirer
  .prompt([
    /*...*/
  ])
  .then((answers) => {
    const { languages } = answers;

    const languagesList = languages
      .map((language) => `* ${language}`)
      .join("\n");
  });
```

This should produce a markdown list like

```md
* HTML
* CSS
* JavaScript
* Node.JS
```

Comment: Excellent thank you. I'll try this in the morning and get back to you.